# In Azure App Service, how do I redirect www to non-www domain?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have hosted my web application on Azure App Service for ease and scalability. My App is working fine on example.com but when i am trying to write [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) i am getting an error stating that: App not found.

I was looking for a stable option so in some blog i get to know we can use **Azure FrontDoor** as CDN service and redirecting also, I tried to use Azure frontdoor and set it up, the domain provided by FrontDoor my App was working fine on that but when i was trying [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) technically it should have redirect to example.com but that didn't happened.

REF:
[Reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189146/azure-front-door-redirect-www-to-non-www)
[Reference 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)
[Reference 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105879/redirect-www-to-non-www-on-azure-dns-zone)
[Reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170246/azure-front-door-keep-custom-url-in-redirects)

Answer (score 1):

**To redirect from www to non-www domain in Azure App Service:**

- Make sure you have configured the DNS records for your custom domain.
- Make sure you have configured Azure Front Door as mentioned in [MSQ&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189146/azure-front-door-redirect-www-to-non-www).
- Create Azure Front Door and select Azure App Service and your Host name as shown below:

[image]

- **Go to `Domain=>Add` and configure the domain by selecting existing DNS Zone :**

[image]

**Configure the endpoint:**

[image]

[image]

- **Once configured DNS mapping/ CNAME record, navigate to `Azure App Service=>custom domains`, add `example.com`:**

[image]

**References:**

[Onboard a root or apex domain to Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)